# jQuery data() cleared when drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable container with some images inserted. Also I have defined some internal values to these images with the [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function. 
Everything is working well untill I move these images inside the contenteditable. Then, all data associated with the images is gone. 
Do you know how to avoid this? or if there is a better solution to assign information to DOM elements?

Comment: Please provide some actual code.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euK2F/) also reported the bug to jQuery: [jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10763)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to assign values to DOM elements within their `data-` attributes.

So instead of `data()`, i'd use

```
set: $('image').attr('data-attr1', 'value1');
get: $('image').attr('data-attr1');
```

Comment: how do you define array attributes?

Comment: You should stringify the JSON objects first before assigning to attributes.
http://json.org/
include json2.js
use JSON.stringify(jsonObject);